How to change date filter format in material react table?
I have a material react table component to display table data in my project, dates and date filters should be in dd.mm.yyyy format, but by default it is mm/dd/yyyy.
After using Localization provider and dayjs adapter dates and filter are correct.
But only when I'm running it in my local environment.
As soon as I'm trying to reach dd.mm.yyyy format inside the docker container it fails and return me back to default mm/dd/yyyy.
The table configuration:
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { MRT_Localization_RU } from 'material-react-table/locales/ru'
import 'dayjs/locale/ru';

const columns = [
    { accessorKey: 'order', header: 'Order', enableHiding: false, size: 120 },
    {
      accessorKey: 'product.sku',
      header: 'SKU',
      enableHiding: true,
      size: 110,
      editVariant: 'select',
      editSelectOptions: fetchedProducts
    },
    {
      accessorFn: row => (row.date ? new Date(row.date) : ''),
      accessorKey: 'date',
      header: 'Date',
      enableHiding: true,
      size: 120,
      Cell: ({ cell }) => cell.getValue()?.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU'),
      filterVariant: 'date',
      filterFn: 'lessThan',
      sortingFn: 'datetime',
    }
]

const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    columns,
    data: fetchedSales,
    localization: MRT_Localization_RU
  })

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="ru">
  <MaterialReactTable table={table} />
</LocalizationProvider>

docker-compose:
client:
    build:
      dockerfile: ClientDocker
    command: >
      sh -c "npm run dev -- --host"
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - 5173:5173


ClientDocker file:
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 3000

COPY ./client/package.json ./client/package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

COPY ./client ./

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]


Why it works correct and as expected without the docker?
The same result with dayjs, moment and luxon locales
Also I made an attempt to install and change default locale inside the docker container, not helped:
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Moscow /etc/localtime

RUN echo 'export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8' >> /etc/profile.d/locale.sh && \
  sed -i 's|LANG=C.UTF-8|LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8|' /etc/profile.d/locale.sh

